# Python : which importing module is calling my function at runtime

Tags: python, module, runtime

I don't know if there is a way to get the information I want, so maybe there isn't.
Anyway, here is my question:

I have a module, say "m.py", with a function , say "def f(): ..."

Now imagine some other modules are importing m.py

in f, I would like to know which module is calling me, at runtime.

is that possible ?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys,inspect,os
_logLevel = 10
def debugPrint(*args,**kwargs):
    if _logLevel > kwargs.get('required_level',0):
        args = list(args)
        info = inspect.stack()[1]
        info = tuple([os.path.basename(info[1]),info[2]])
        args.insert(0,"%s %s:"%info)
        sys.stdout.write(" ".join("%s"%arg for arg in args))

debugPrint("Hello world!")
```

is a method I like to use that might help you